# Drupal 7 Ajax GET - Error 400 (Hook_menu)

Tags: javascript, ajax, routes

I am trying to send an array back to Drupal to save in a database table. I'm getting an error 400 though when inspecting in the console and the url seems correct:

> GET http://localhost/audiophreak/callback/%?[1,2,3,4,5,6,45,46,47] 400
>   (Bad Request)

Here is my hook_menu:

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_menu().
*/
function my_db_module_menu() {
  $items['callback/%?'] = array(
    'title' => 'My callback',
    'description' => 'Desc',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_getinfo',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page arguments' => array(1),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Here is my callback:

```
/**
 * My callback
 */
function mymodule_getinfo($data) {

echo drupal_json_decode($data);


  // //Parse the data and input it into the database
  // $result = db_insert('my_db')
  // ->fields(array(
    // 'nid' => $data->node,
    // 'uid' => $data->user,
    // 'progress' => $data->progress,
  // ))
  // ->execute();
}
```

And here is my AJAX

```
//Data
    var post = plnzVideoTracker.progress


    //Begin Ajax
    $.ajax({
          url: '/audiophreak/callback/%',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: JSON.stringify(post),
          success: function(data) {
            if(data == "success")
            {
            $('.status').attr("innerHTML","<font color='green'>Name submitted successfully!</font>");
            }
            else
            {
              $('.status').attr("innerHTML","<font color='red'>Name submit failed!</font>");
            }
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
              $(document).ready(function () {
              $('.status').attr("innerHTML","Loading....");
            });
            },
            'error': function(data) {
              $(document).ready(function () {
              $('.status').attr("innerHTML","ERROR OCCURRED!");
            });
          }
     });
```

plnzVideoTracker.progress is an array inside of an object literal if that has anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` symbol is type of placeholder in hook_menu item. You can read more about it here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7#sec_path_wildcards.

For you example I suggest to use the following:

```
function my_db_module_menu() {
  $items['callback'] = array(
    'title' => 'My callback',
    'description' => 'Desc',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_getinfo',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Simple path  - `callback`.

And use the following AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/callback',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {data: post},
  ...
```

By this way, you can access the data in your webhook more simply:

```
/**
 * My callback
 */
function mymodule_getinfo() {
  $data = !empty($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : array();

  // do what you want...
}
```

Comment: Hmm now getting the error: POST http://localhost/callback 404 (Not Found). Url seems to be deprecating the base path

Comment: Did you cleared the cache before try to access it?

Comment: Yes, i'll double check everything again though. uno momento.

Comment: kala4ek, I seem to have solved it partially thanks to you. I set the callback in the ajax request to a relative path: $.ajax({
          url: '/audiophreak/callback',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {data: post},
          success: function(response){
                    alert(response);
                    //echo what the server sent back...
                }
         }); and used if(isset($_POST['data']) && !empty($_POST['data'])) {
        // echo json_encode(array("blablabla"=>$variable));
        echo json_encode($_POST['data']);
    }

Comment: This now alerts the array I am sending. Thank you!